# AngularJS - Issue trying to access an Array to return an alert

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular and I am trying to access to some content which is inside an array.

on this line you will see `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.lineItems))` which is returning `[[]]` on the browser console. If I inspect/make a breakpoint on the same line, this is the info I have:

```
> 0: Array[0]
length: 1
> __proto__: Array[0]
```

if you click on `> 0: Array[0]` then another part will open showing this

```
> 0: Array[0]
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array[0]
> length: 1
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

now, what I need to do is that when `0: Array[0]` show an alert which is `noLinesAlert.show()`

this is my code which is actually not working because I am confuse and I do not know how to access to the info I need:

```
$scope.lineItems = lines;
  console.log(lines);
  console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.lineItems));
  if ($scope.lineItems.length === 0) {
    noLinesAlert.show();
  }else {
    noLinesAlert.hide();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you described you need this:

```
if ($scope.lineItems[0].length === 0) {
    noLinesAlert.show();
} else {
    noLinesAlert.hide();
}
```

Comment: I am very new for this, is the same if I do:

```if (!$scope.lineItems[0].length)``` instead of ```if ($scope.lineItems[0].length === 0)``` ??? @dfsq

Comment: In this case yes, since `length` is always a number so result is going to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

actually the proper way I just implement: `if(JSON.stringify($scope.lineItems) === '[[]]')`

Comment: Also you can write `if ($scope.lineItems.length === 1 && $scope.lineItems[0].length === 0) {}`.